# How do I filter my data for the same time last year - Power Query

Tags: filtering, dax, powerquery

I'm making an excel file that will be used for a report on sickness absence.

We are looking at the last 100 days (which I've been able to do with a simple filter in my Applied Steps) and we want to compare to the same time last year plus 100 days before that date AND look at 50 days after that date.

How can I filter for this in Power Query? Or do I have to write a custom formula? (In which case, does anyone know what and where to write it)

Idea is to be able to run this report every day/week and give updates on how we're doing in the winter in comparison to last year.

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use the drop down filter atop the date column ... Date filters ... between ... and enter some random set of dates like 1/30/2019 through 1/30/2020

That generates this code

```
= Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each [date] >= #date(2019, 1, 30) and [date] <= #date(2020, 1, 30))
```

edit it for your desired date range which could be like this

```
= Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each [date] >= Date.AddDays(targetdate, -465) and [date] <= Date.AddDays(targetdate, -315))
```

I assume -465 which is last year (365 days prior) plus 100 days back, and -315 which is -365+50

As for what to use instead of **targetdate** ... you didn't tell us .. perhaps hardcode a date #date(2019,10,31), use whatever you had in your original filter, or maybe the maximum of the current date column

```
List.Max(#"priorstepname"[date])
```

Comment: Just to check, did this work?